# docker run sed doesn't work

Tags: sed, docker

I'm approaching to [Docker](https://www.docker.io). I created an image debootstraping Debian Jessie and I want to add the `contrib` section to APT sources file.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` contents are:

```
$ docker run some/image cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://debian.fastweb.it/debian jessie main
deb http://debian.fastweb.it/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

I want them to be:

```
deb http://debian.fastweb.it/debian jessie main contrib
deb http://debian.fastweb.it/debian jessie-updates main contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

So I ran this command:

```
docker run some/image sed -i 's/main/main contrib/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Which exits without errors; but it doesn't update `/etc/apt/sources.list` contents:

```
$ docker run some/image cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://debian.fastweb.it/debian jessie main
deb http://debian.fastweb.it/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not change the image. You started a container, based on the image. Then you ran your sed command and changed the file contents. Check `docker ps -a` to see the id of the container that just closed. If you use `docker cp` to extract your file you should see that it was changed as expected (assuming your sed command was ok).

You could also create a Dockerfile

```
FROM some/image
RUN sed -i 's/main/main contrib/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
# this command is just temporary, you probably are going to do something else
CMD cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and run the new image `docker run some/new-image` to get the expected output.

Conclusion - you probably want to do run your sed command in the original images Dockerfile.

Comment: You are right, if I check the contents of the `sources.list` of the container in which I ran the command they are updated. I still have to grasp the difference between an image and a container; could you explain how to modify the image? Could you suggest a workflow to do these kind of things? (a link to some related resource would be great :) )

Comment: No problem if not, I'll make my way ;)

Comment: the two correct flows are: 1)docker run --> docker commit --> docker run; 2)you can build image from Dockerfile and run container from the image.

Comment: Have a look at the Glossary in the official Docker documentation: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/terms/image/